# Como pegar elemento pelo id dentro de um bloco retornado pelo getElementById()

Tags: javascript

## Seguinte...

Quero encontrar um elemento (formulário) que está dentro de um bloco. Eu uso o `.getElementById();` para pegar esse bloco.

Depois de pegar o bloco, quero achar o formulário que está nesse bloco para poder incluir um elemento antes desse formulário. Estou tentando dessa forma, e até agora, não consegui:

#### javascript

```
var boardElem = document.getElementById('board-01');
var formEl = boardElem.children('#formNewTask');
```

Não funcionou... Aí tentei usar assim também:

```
var formEl = boardElem.getElementById('formNewTask');
```

E o erro gerado é esse:
**Uncaught TypeError: boardElem.getElementById is not a function**

Estou acostumado com jQuery. Mas estou desenvolvendo um projeto sem utilizar o framework. Alguma luz?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você possui o id do formulário em mãos? Ele é conhecido?

Comment: Outra pergunta: existe algum outro formulário na página?

Comment: Acabei de conseguir, Danilo! O id era "#formNewTask". Existirão vários formulários na página sim (eu nem deveria tentar pegar pelo ID mesmo). De qualquer forma, obrigado! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consegui...

Resolvi o problema. Eu precisava de um seletor p/ encontrar o elemento.
Tentei o `children`, `getElementById`, `getElementByTagName`, ...

E não estava lembrando do principal... O `querySelector`.

#### Funcionou assim:

```
var boardElem = document.getElementById('board-01');
var formEl = boardElem.querySelector('form');
boardElem.insertBefore(novoElemento, formEl);
```

Como terei apenas 1 **form** dentro do **board**, não vou usar ID. E sim o nome da tag como parâmetro no seletor. Estava sofrendo com isso!

Comment: Por isso pedi mais informações nos comentários, para entender melhor sua estrutura =)

Comment: Pois é... Final do expediente, a cabeça começa a falhar rsrsrs. Obrigado, Danilo!